How can we automatically resize extremly large images during upload?
When uploading large images (e.g., those with dimensions exceeding 7500 pixels), the system doesn't automatically crop them to the custom size of 2400 pixels using the following code:
<?php
add_image_size('custom_size_2400', 2400);

Additionally, there are no restrictions on uploading images of any resolution. Currently, to achieve the desired size, you must manually crop the image to a smaller size before it will resize correctly.
To address this, there should be a setting that automatically converts the uploaded image to the maximum allowed size, after which it will resize according to the specified dimensions.

Since 5.3, WP has a limit of 2560 pixels in either direction, images above that size will not be processed by default. https://foliovision.com/2021/11/full-size-images-wordpress

@C3roe When I upload image with 7500(w) x 7500(h) then its creating the variation. But not above 7500

Maybe something in your setup has already modified the threshold value mentioned in the linked article. Or maybe your server simply fails at the resizing task, because it runs out of memory. If that's the case, then you should go look for a solution that resizes the images on the client already, and then uploads the smaller version to the server. There's probably already plugins for that, I suppose.

You are absolutely right. I have tried big_image_size_threshold filter working fine.

Since 5.3, WP has a limit of 2560 pixels in either direction, images above that size will not be processed by default. foliovision.com/2021/11/full-size-images-wordpress –
Worked below code. Thanks @C3roe
function td_big_image_size_threshold($threshold, $imagesize, $file, $attachment_id)
{
    return 20096;
}
add_filter('big_image_size_threshold', 'td_big_image_size_threshold', 10, 4);


The easiest solution, I also use it, is here. https://www.dropzone.dev/
html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>File Upload</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.9.2/dropzone.min.css">
    <style>
        .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-progress {
            width: 0%;
            height: 25px;
            background-color: #4CAF50;
    margin-left: -60px;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="phppot-container tile-container text-center">
        <h2>File Upload</h2>
        <form action="upload.php" class="dropzone" id="myDropzone"></form>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.9.2/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
            paramName: "file", // filename handle to upload
            maxFilesize: 2, // MB
            maxFiles: 2, // number of files allowed to upload
            acceptedFiles: ".png, .jpg, .jpeg, .gif", // file types allowed to upload
         resizeWidth: 600,
          autoQueue: true,

            init: function () {
                this.on("uploadprogress", function (file, progress) {
                    var progressBar = file.previewElement.querySelector(".dz-progress");
                    progressBar.style.width = progress + "%";
                    progressBar.innerHTML = progress + "%";
                });

                this.on("success", function (file, response) {
                    var progressBar = file.previewElement.querySelector(".dz-progress");
                    progressBar.classList.add("bg-success");
                    progressBar.innerHTML = "Uploaded";
                });

                this.on("error", function (file, errorMessage) {
                    var progressBar = file.previewElement.querySelector(".dz-progress");
                    progressBar.classList.add("bg-danger");
                    progressBar.innerHTML = errorMessage;
                });
            }
        
        
        
        
        };
    </script>
</body>

</html>

php code if you want to connect with mysql
    <?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_FILES['file'])) {
   $file = $_FILES['file'];

   // file to be uploaded to this directory
   // should have sufficient file permissions
   $uploadDir = 'uploads/';

   // unique file name generated for the uploaded file
   $fileName = uniqid() . '_' . $file['name'];

   
  require 'dbConfig.php'; 
   
   
   // moving the uploaded file from temp directory to uploads directory
   if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $uploadDir . $fileName)) {
       $insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO zfilestest (file_name, uploaded_on) VALUES ('".$fileName."', NOW())"); 
       echo 'File uploaded successfully.';
   } else {
       echo 'Failed to upload file.';
   }
}
?>


andreas you were might right but we are talking about default image upload in WordPress. At that time it will generate multiple variations as per required.
